# How do you set different lines with different colours?

Tags: ios, swift, colors, drawing, drawrect

I've been attempting to give each line a different colour, but every time I move the sliders responsible for providing the lines with colour, every single line changes its colour. I've tried placing the values I get from the sliders into the for loop, but for some reason it doesn't give each line a different colour. The storage variables are the variables which I'm using to store the values from the sliders defined in my view controller class.

To clarify what I'm trying to do, here's an example:
Line 1 could be red and line 2 could be purple.

Here's my current attempt at changing the colour of the lines:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class DrawClass: UIView {


var lines:[Line] = []
var lastPoint: CGPoint!


required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.layer.zPosition = 1

}




override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent){
    if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {
        lastPoint =  touch.locationInView(self)
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent){
    if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {
        var newPoint = touch.locationInView(self)
        lines.append(Line(start: lastPoint, end: newPoint))
        lastPoint = newPoint
    }
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
}






override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()


    var storage: Float = ViewController.simple.storage1
    var storage2: Float = ViewController.simple.storage2
    var storage3: Float = ViewController.simple.storage3

    for line in lines
    {
        CGContextBeginPath(context)
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, line.start.x, line.start.y)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, line.end.x, line.end.y)
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, CGFloat(storage), CGFloat(storage2), CGFloat(storage3), 1)
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5)
        CGContextStrokePath(context)
    }



}


}
```

Does it have anything to do with this line of code:

```
lines.append(Line(start: lastPoint, end: newPoint))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When drawRect is called it is redrawing all of the lines. You need to associate colors with lines. You could do that buy adding color properties onto your Line object and setting them in touchesMoved then using those properties in drawRect to set the StrokeColor. For example add to Line:

```
   var redValue:CGFloat
   var greenValue:CGFloat
   var blueValue:CGFloat
```

In touchesMoved, probably really should be touchesEnded, say something like:

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent){
    if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {
        var newPoint = touch.locationInView(self)
        lines.append(Line(start: lastPoint, end: newPoint,redValue:ViewController.simple.storage1,greenValue:ViewController.simple.storage2,blueValue:ViewController.simple.storage3))
        lastPoint = newPoint
    }
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

Then in drawRect:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    for line in lines
    {
        CGContextBeginPath(context)
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, line.start.x, line.start.y)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, line.end.x, line.end.y)
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, line.redValue, line.greenValue, line.blueValue, 1)
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5)
        CGContextStrokePath(context)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It's functioning as intended now! However, I had to convert the line colour values to CGFloat and remove the start point and end point variables since I wasn't using those parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing the color change for each color in your graphic.
If you want to change the color just for one segment (for example the first), you have to add a test, like

```
if line == 0 {
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, CGFloat(storage), CGFloat(storage2), CGFloat(storage3), 1)
} else {
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, CGFloat(0.0), CGFloat(0.), CGFloat(0.0), 1)
}
```

If all segments can have a different color, you can store the color int the line object, and retrieve it like the points